# When Calling a JQuery via ID element, it shows twice

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, jquery, spservices

When I am calling a JQuery using the ID element in the Div tag, its showing up twice.  Is there something I need to do to stop the double showing?  Below is my code and under that is the outcome (using jquery-3.3.1.min.js and jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js). Thanks:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
       $().SPServices({
         operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
         userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
         //async: false,
         completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
          switch (true) {
            case $(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='1 Awards Members']").length == 1:
              htmlText="1 Awards Members";
              $('#permText').append(htmlText);
              break;
            case $(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='2 Awards Members']").length == 1:
              htmlText="2 Awards Members";
              $('#permText').append(htmlText);
              break;
            case $(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='awards Owners']").length == 1:
              htmlText="Awards Owners";
              $('#permText').append(htmlText);
              break;
            default:
              alert("Your account has not been granted permissions.");
          }
    //was here, $('#permText).append("Awards Owners");...still duplicates
          }
       });
    
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Actually it can be all three.  We have 3 different environments we are supporting

Comment: Thank you for your input.  The screen shot was from office 365, which we were able to use on 2013 and 2010 (some what). So again, to reply to your original post, it can.  In regards to wasting time, I apologize for wasting anyone’s time, in particular, yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out.  Add a web part zone using Designer.  Got this from the following:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7921de59-0fa1-4fa3-bb16-11d0a64d297f/spservices-and-datatables-loading-twice?forum=sharepointdevelopment